# OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory in jetty websocket with 32 Bit

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, 32bit-64bit, bytebuffer

I wrote an application that is connection to a websocket server using jetty websocket. When using JDK 1.8.0 (64 bit) all seems fine but when switching to JDK 1.8.0 (32 bit) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
   at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:693)
   at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
   at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BufferUtil.allocateDirect(BufferUtil.java:133)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteBufferPool.newByteBuffer(ByteBufferPool.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.MappedByteBufferPool.acquire(MappedByteBufferPool.java:67)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher$Flusher.batch(FrameFlusher.java:65)
```

I think it has to do with the fact that 32 bit can't handle the requested byte buffer size.

So the easiest solution would be to switch to 64 bit but we have a lot of customers with 32-bit systems: is there any easier solution?

I already tried to change the JVM settings with various parameters
but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue: I had set the Buffersize of the Connection/Connections too high because I also transport files. I set it to 1024*1024*1024, which means 1GB.

I changed it to 50 MB (more than I need) and it works.

```
session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
session.getPolicy().setMaxBinaryMessageSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
session.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
session.getPolicy().setMaxTextMessageSize(BUFFER_SIZE);
```